# Micro-service architecture in .NET Core: pattern or library for services to call each other

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

I am implementing a `micro-service architecture` for the first time.

Some of my services (.NET Core Web APIs) need to communicate with each other through HTTP requests. For that purpose, I am injecting a wrapper around `HttpClient`.

But I suspect that I am reinventing the wheel. Among micro-service practitioners, is there a pattern or even a third-party library to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In a micro-service architecture, the most important thing is a clear separation of concerns and application boundaries. Imagine a simple setup, with Product and Price micro services

[image]

An important concept is each service is master of data, and owns its own database. In this example,

- a client of the 'Product' service will make an HTTP call to the Product API.
- the product API will make a call to the Price API to get prices for the products
- the product API therefore depends on the Price API to create a response

These are the synchronous parts of the process, generally achieved through HTTP calls across boundaries. You'll also have asynchronous parts of your solution, in this example,

- the Price API publishes an event to a bus whenever a price is changed
- the product API publishes an event whenever a product is created
- There may be one or more subscribers to these events, that will respond and probably call an API to retrieve the changed data.

The critical parts of this are clearly defining your API and message contracts, understanding if things will be async or sync, having the right level of telemetry across the entire architecture to track and understand distributed system behaviour, and keeping everything as independently buildable/testable/deployable components.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, if you're not using containers, start, along with orchestration (both natively supported in Visual Studio, assuming you have Docker, etc. actually installed). Among the many benefits, you can reference your services via hostname without having to worry about ports and different locations for different environments.

As far as actual communication goes. There's not really a magic solution here. `HttpClient` is what you use, of course, and generally, yes, you want to have a wrapper around that to abstract away the low-level HTTP communication stuff, so the rest of your code can simply call simple methods on that wrapper.

If you aren't using `IHttpClientFactory`, start. If you already have a wrapper class, you're halfway there, and with that, not only do you get efficient management of `HttpMessageHandler`s so you don't exhaust your server's connection pool, but you can also use the Polly integration to handle transient HTTP errors and even do retry policies, circuit breakers, etc. for your microservice connections.

Finally, there is the [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) library which can make things a tad more straight-forward. I find it to have more use with huge third-party APIs like Facebook, Google, etc., though. Since microservices should by design be simple, you're probably not saving much code over just having your own wrapper class. Regardless, the way it works is that you define an interface that represents the API, and then Refit uses that to actually make appropriate requests. It's kind of like a wrapper class for free, but you still need to create the interface.

Comment: I'll second that kubernetes.  If you have more than 2 containers in a pod, they can call with localhost.  If you have containers in separate pods, you'll expose the container(s) as a SERVICE : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/       https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/

Comment: Yes, kubernetes is the de facto standard for production deployments. Personally, I prefer developing with just docker-compose for basic orchestration.